# cannot convert ' const char' to 'const char*'

Tags: c++

I try to define a char array by using follow method. But I got an error.
What's the problem with it?

```
const char *str = "I am Mike";
char stack_back[strlen(*str)+1];
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You have 2 lines of code. Which line gives the error? And what is the exact error message?

Comment: This: `char stack_back[strlen(*str)+1];` doesn't make sense.  You're taking the length of a string dereference.

Comment: It's `strlen(str)`

Comment: C or C++? It matters, especially here.

Comment: Furthermore, C++ standard does not allow variable length arrays

Comment: `char stack_back[strlen(*str)+1];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime value.

Answer (score 3):

By dereferencing `str`, you get a character. `strlen()` is expecting a string, but instead it is seeing `'I'`. Remove the `*` from the definition.

```
const char *str = "I am Mike";
char stack_back[strlen(str)+1];
```

Comment: As long as this question is tagged as `C++`, the array is not valid.

Comment: Should note that standard C++ does not allow VLAs -- although this may be C and not C++ code, hard to tell when both are tagged.

Comment: Yea I think this is C code, OP has been asking C related questions recently but has used C++ in the past. They might not be clear on the differences yet.